# Horizontal scroller edge detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

How would I modify my script so it will detect the edge and not scroll more than the container width?

Mark-up and JS included and also JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/carlozdre/4HSLb/8/

```
<div id="content">
          <div class="inner">
          <img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/300" />
          <img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/300" />
          <img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/300" /> 
          <img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/300" />
          <img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/300" />
          <img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/300" />
          </div>
</div>

<div style="">
 <a class="left" href="#">LEEEEFT</a>
 <a class="right" href="#">RIGHHHT</a>
</div>

<style>
#content { float: left; width: 600px; overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap; max-width: 3000px;}
.inner {width: 300px;}
</style>

$(function () {
    $('.left').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.inner').animate({
            marginLeft: "-=" + 20 + "px"
        }, 'fast');

    });


    $('.right').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.inner').animate({
            marginLeft: "+=" + 20 + "px"
        }, 'fast');

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes to ensure the size of the inner container is fixed to the size of the images within, and then check the left and right position of the inner container.

You are also better to animate to a specific coordinate rather than adding or subtracting from the previous one, as it will handle fast clicks much better.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4HSLb/13/

**Markup:**

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/300" />
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/300" />
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/300" />
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/300" />
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/300" />
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/300" />
    </div>
</div>
<div style=""> <a class="left" href="#">LEEEEFT</a>
 <a class="right" href="#">RIGHHHT</a>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 610px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 3000px;
}
.inner {
    background:#444;
    height:300px;
}
.inner img {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

**Script:**

```
var left = 0;
var contentWidth = 0;
var innerWidth = 0;
var imgCount = 0;
var imgWidth = 310;

$(function () {
    contentWidth = parseInt($('#content').innerWidth());
    left = parseInt($('.inner').css('margin-left'));
    imgCount = $('.inner img').size()
    innerWidth = parseInt(imgCount * imgWidth);

    $('.inner').width(innerWidth + "px");

    $('.left').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        updatePos(imgWidth);
        if (left <= 0) {
            $('.inner').animate({
                marginLeft: left + "px"
            }, 'fast');
        }
    });

    $('.right').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        updatePos(0 - imgWidth);
        if (left >= 0 - innerWidth + (imgWidth * 2)) {
            $('.inner').animate({
                marginLeft: left + "px"
            }, 'fast');
        }
    });

});

function updatePos(distance) {
    console.log("NewPos: " + (left + distance));
    console.log(0 - innerWidth);
    if (left + distance <= 0 && left + distance >= 0 - innerWidth + (imgWidth * 2)) {
        left = left + distance;
    }
    //console.log(left);
}
```

**Edit:**
Updated to prevent over scrolling when fast clicking.

**Edit 2:**
Updated code to allow the number of images in view to be easily changed.  Rather than editing the example code above, here is an example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4HSLb/14/

Comment: thanks, it does make sense but if I scroll all the way to the right, and then all the way to the left it won't stop at the first image but scroll more to the left?

Comment: Edited answer to handle fast clicking better

Comment: answer accepted, I understand why and how now! I am still struggling to figure out what should I change if I'd only like to use a very wide image instead of several

Comment: I've made some edits to the code to show how you would achieve this - http://jsfiddle.net/4HSLb/14/ - basically you have to set the number of images in view as another variable and use that to determine the right position.

Comment: thank you very much for your help; what I meant really is using a wide image like http://lorempixel.com/900/300/, but just the one image, with the container being of course, less than that!

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - so you can pan around the image?  Ever thought of using http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ to move the inner element around inside the parent container?

Comment: that would be a bit too much for what I am trying to achieve/understand - this is what I meant - http://jsfiddle.net/carlozdre/RMEuh/

Comment: fantastic! have a great day Jamie (the link to 'the process' from pricing.aspx is wrong)